# Shell: Git Repo Creation Script is NOT Pushing Remote Upstream

Tags: git, shell

Below I have a shell script that is not pushing it's created remote branches upstream.

I tested the script locally and found that the branches are indeed being created however, it seems to break once the script reaches the line `git push -u origin master`

If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong it will be much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh
set +x
localPath=$HOME/repos
token=""
instance=https://gitlab.####.com/api/v4
namespace_id=2 #This is the Flag group on our Gitlab instance. 

# On first use, prompt user to input the Gitlab Private API token. Then, store it for future uses as token.txt. 
if [ -f token.txt ]
    then
    read token < token.txt
else 
    read -p "Please input your Gitlab Private API Token from your user profile (https://gitlab.####.com/profile/account): " token
    echo $token > token.txt
    $token < token.txt
fi

for eachRepoName
    do
        #Local Work
        mkdir -p $localPath
        mkdir -p $localPath/$eachRepoName
        cp Master-Ignore-List.txt $localPath/$eachRepoName/.gitignore
        cd $localPath/$eachRepoName/
        echo "pre-git"
        git init
        touch README.md
        git add README.md .gitignore
        echo "about to commit"
        git commit -m "First Commit"
        #End Local Work

        curl -w "%{http_code}\n" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $token" -X POST "$instance/projects?name=$eachRepoName&namespace_id=$namespace_id"

        git remote add origin https://gitlab.####.com/flag/$eachRepoName.git
        git push -u origin master
        git checkout -b development
        git push -u origin development 
        git remote set-head origin master 
        git branch -a
    done
```

Comment: Does the push give you an error?

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot to mention----fatal: repository <url> not found AND ----error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/master----gets thrown when the script reaches the line to push upstream @EncryptedWatermelon

Comment: One issue I could imagine is that maybe Gitlab hasn't fully finished initializing the new repository by the time you're trying to push. Purely for troubleshooting I'd try to `sleep` for a bit before trying the first push. If that makes a difference, you could implement something like a retry mechanism.

Comment: @JanKrüger Thanks so much, this is exactly what i needed to do!